# How to install Windows 10 on a non bootable NVMe drive?

Tags: windows-10, installation, multi-boot, nvme

It all starts with me trying to provide a small upgrade to my trusty computer (Asus A88XM-Plus, AMD A10, 256 + 128 Sata SSDs).
I needed more space so I added a Samsung NVMe drive on a PCIe adapter. My intention was to move the Windows 10 installation to the NVMe while keeping one SSD for boot and a Linux Mint system.

First, this did not go like I expected. I couldn't expand the Windows partitions because of the way Windows creates them. I couldn't boot the Windows as somehow boot infos disappeared (It did boot fine once though... once). I kept getting the 0x00..00e error. I couldn't use Windows repair tools as without a bootable Windows, I was unable to create a Windows USB key. I finally managed thanks to an old vm on my other Linux box but this didn't work either. Some tools (bootrec /fixmbr) worked and some tools (bootrec /RebuildCDB) did not work because "requested system device" not found.
So after spending 3 full days trying to fix this, I gave up and came to accept the need to reinstall everything.

My LinuxMint being fresh and working, I focused on Windows. I used the Windows 10 USB key to install Windows with:
only the NVMe drive in the box.
CSM disabled.
Secure boot disabled.
Then
Deleted all partitions on the NVMe drive in the custom install menu of the installer.
Selected the blank space
launch the installation
At first reboot, I shutdown the computer to remove the USB stick and insert the SSD with the Linux so I have a bootable drive.
Start the Linux system
Update grub
Reboot
Now I have an entry in the Grub menu for the Windows system and I can start it... or so I thought.
Grub kept telling me that there was no such device. I checked the UUID of the drive, it was correct. By listing the partitions (ls) I realized that Grub doesn't seem to see/load the NVMe drive.

After reading some more, I find out that Windows can actually use an existing EFI partition if it finds it at install time. So I start again but this time, I leave the SSD with the Linux in place so that the Windows installer can use the EFI partition on it.
Same process about delete all partition in the NVMe and selecting the empty space for installation. It seems to work. The Windows manager only created 2 partitions on the NVMe and obviously put data in the EFI partition of the SSD.
The computer reboots and in the BIOS, I can see one more UEFI entry named "Windows Boot Manager". Great, I select it to continue the installation... or so I thought.
Windows greets me with the exact same 0x00...00e error telling me that my system need repair.

This leads me to think that Windows as well does not load the NVMe at boot time and thus cannot find the actual system partition.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: "This leads me to think that Windows as well does not load the NVMe at boot time and thus cannot find the actual system partition." - This is incorrect.  If you see an entry for Windows Boot Manager it means, your system is detecting the MBR/EFI partition, or your boot order is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the entry in the UEFI and the boot manager is generated by the EFI partition which is on the bootable SSD as mentioned in my post. This is unrelated to the NVMe which contains the system itself and which cannot be found at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple paths around this but I strongly advise to install the operating system on a disk connected to the motherboard. This is because Windows must load a driver to run the PCIe card and this is fragile which is probably why Windows can't boot in your case. We have had a system when Windows was running fine until an update causes it do fail to initialize the PCIe disk card and we had to boot from a recovery disk.

It would be best if you installed both Linux and Windows on the SATA SSD in separate partitions and create two partitions for them on the NVMe for data. On the system disk you should have everything to boot both systems and extra data (home, user, media, etc) on the NVMe which will also let both systems get a performance boost!

The point is that even if you manage to make it work, it can break and would be troublesome to fix. It will save a ton of headaches if you allow the boot process to be simple on both operating systems. There is another way I can think but this is not something I tried and that is to run Windows under a VM with the NVMe as its physical  disk. That way the drive access would be emulated bu the VM layer and Windows would not know it was on a PCIe card. Of course, this would encur the overhead of virtualization, so it depends what you use Windows for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had not taken the stability of the system in account. I would have liked to experiment a bit about a potential solution but it is maybe wiser to set back the system as it was with just the nvme as extra.

Answer (score -1):

It's my understanding that to boot to an NVMe drive on a PCIe device, you must boot to UEFI BIOS because non-UEFI BIOS won't recognize the NVMe drive when booting. Also, I think that the BIOS requires that all drives be GPT in order to change to UEFI.
If I am wrong, I hope that someone will correct me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).